# Capital chapter names in book class

Tags: chapters, books

In the book `documentclass` how can you make the chapters be in capital letters?

For example:

Chapter 1 --> CHAPTER 1

etc...

Comment: In order to make a sequence of capital letters look decent, it's really important to apply some letterspacing, say with the help of the `microtype` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `book` document class has a low-level macro named `\chaptername`, but what's used in the typesetting of chapter headers is `\@chapapp`. It's best to leave `\chaptername` alone and modify `\@chapapp`, by applying (a) `\MakeUppercase` to its argument and (b) a modest amount of letter-spacing to the all-caps string; without some letter-spacing, strings of all-caps letters can easily look very "blocky" and dense.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype} % for '\textls' macro

\makeatletter % default is "\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}"
\renewcommand\@chapapp{\textls[40]{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\chapter{Good morning}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If your document has one or more chapter-level appendices, and assuming you'll want the prefix string "Appendix" to be converted to uppercase letters as well, you will need to provide the following instructions after `\appendix`:

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@chapapp{\textls[40]{\MakeUppercase{\appendixname}}}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: It works but I get this error: `Package microtype Error: Letterspacing currently doesn't work with xetex.`

Comment: @Adam - (It would have been helpful to mention earlier that you use XeLaTeX.) Sadly, `microtype` doesn't "do" letterspacing under XeLaTeX -- but it does work under LuaLaTeX; is that an option for you. If you're committed to XeLaTeX, I'm afraid letterspacing isn't available to you via the `\textls` macro.

Comment: Don't worry, I just removed the letterspacing and everything works fine . :)

Answer (score 2):

A low level way of doing this is to simply have

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{CHAPTER}
```

In your preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\chaptername{CHAPTER}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

[image]