# Capital part names in book class

Tags: books

This is a follow-up question [to the one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296428/capital-chapter-names-in-book-class) about the capitalization of chapter names in the book class. Now I would like to make capital the names of book parts in the book class.

Part 1 --> PART 1

I use ShareLaTeX with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *Bold,
    ItalicFont = *It,
    BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Mapping = tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping = tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range = \varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range = \int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you haven't even tried using `\renewcommand\partname{PART}`? If this doesn't work, please provide more information regarding your setup. Some things (like packages or language settings) influence the availability or formatting of sectional units.

Comment: @Werner That was the second thing that I tried...The first was very shameful to admit. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for some (but not all) languages.

```
\documentclass{book}

\let\oldpartname\partname

\renewcommand{\partname}{\MakeUppercase{\oldpartname}}


\begin{document}

\part{Foo}

\end{document}
```

Here's a `babel` based setup (for some arbitrary languages, say German and Spanish)

`\MakeUppercase` acts on a stored copy of `\partname` -- `\let\oldpartname\partname` generates this copy.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ngerman,spanish]{babel}


\addto\captionsspanish{\let\oldpartname\partname
\renewcommand{\partname}{\MakeUppercase{\oldpartname}}}

\addto\captionsngerman{\let\oldpartname\partname
\renewcommand{\partname}{\MakeUppercase{\oldpartname}}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\otherlanguage{ngerman}
\part{Foo}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\part{Foobar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This too doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Adam: It would have helped if you would have provided your `fontspec` related stuff before!

Comment: Sorry! Now it works. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  ItalicFont = *It,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\makeatletter
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \protected@edef\partname{\MakeUppercase{\partname}}%
}
\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \protected@edef\partname{\MakeUppercase{\partname}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Τίτλος}

\selectlanguage{english}

\part{Title}

\end{document}
```

When `\selectlanguage{<language>}` or `\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}` is scanned, LaTeX will process `\captions<language>` (for instance `\captionsgreek`). In this phase `\partname` is set to some language dependent string. With the trick

```
\protected@edef\partname{\MakeUppercase{\partname}}
```

we tell LaTeX that `\partname` is the uppercase version of the just defined string.

Note that `\begin{document}` executes `\selectlanguage{greek}` (because this is the last selected language), so everything comes out right.

[image]

[image]